# Uniform Probability Measure on $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Hello this problem I am working on has four parts, and I have figured out the first three, but I am stuck on the fourth.

For some clarification, the title of the problem I am working on is, Uniform Probability Measure on $\mathbb{N}$? That is why I titled my question so. In searching for a solution to this problem, I found out that such a thing does not exist so I am not asserting that I may have found one or anything like that.

> For each $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ define $$\rho_n(A)= \frac{1}{n}|A\cap[1,n]|,$$ and say that A has density $\rho(A)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\rho_n(A)$ if that limit exists. Let $D=\{ A\subset\mathbb{N}:\rho(A) \text{exists}\}.$
>
> 1) Show that $D$ is closed under complements.
>
> 2) Show that $D$ is closed under finite disjoint unions.
>
> 3) Show that $D$ is not closed under countable disjoint unions.
>
> 4) Show that $D$ is not closed under finite non-disjoint unions.

For 1) I found that for any $A\in D,$ $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \rho_n(A^c)=1-\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \rho_n(A)$ using the $\varepsilon$ definition of limit of a sequence.

For 2) I get the answer to be the sum of the limits, again using the $\varepsilon$ definition and this time the triangle inequality.

For 3) I defined a countable disjoint sequence so that the $\rho_n \text{'s}$ of their union oscillates between $3/4$ and $1/2$.

I want to do something similar as 3) for 4), but I am a little stuck as to how to find a finite number of sets that will give me a nice oscillation like that (I would prefer to find 2 such sets). I do know that the only way to get the sequence to diverge is to make it oscillate in some way. Otherwise, we would get convergence because the sequence is bounded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will answer the question title - it does not exist. For the simple reason that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a = +\infty$ for any $a>0$. I'll consider the body later - but it might help (myself and other readers) to explain how the two are related.

Comment: Sorry, that was just the title of the problem. I believe the point of the problem is to show that the given $\rho$ does not work. There is a part b) to the problem, but I haven't gotten to that yet. I have made an edit to the question to explain this.

Comment: Not trying to be argumentative. It is just helpful to include such context. Otherwise readers may assume you are trying to prove something that isn't true. Your edit to the question makes it clear that isn't the case, thank you.

Comment: Does $|A\cap[1,n]|$ mean  the cardinality (counting measure) of $A\cap[1,n]$?  If so, $\rho$ is not countable additive. For instance, $\rho(\mathbb N)=1$, but for each fixed $k\in \mathbb N$, $\rho(\{k\})=0$, and $\mathbb N =\sum_{k \in \mathbb N} \{k\}$.   So, even if you succeed to prove that $D$ has the 4 properties you listed, $\rho$ will not be an uniform probability measure on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes $|\circ|$ indicates the cardinality of $\circ$. If you read my edit to the question, I only titled my question this because that is what the problem is titled. I am just asking for help showing the $D$ is not closed under finite non-disjoint unions.

Comment: Then, as I explained in my previous comment, $\rho$ is NOT countably additive and so $\rho$ is NOT a probability measure on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a little confused. I am not asserting that $\rho$ is a probability measure. I am looking to find exactly two sets with nonempty intersection, that are both in $D$ but their union is not in $D$.

Comment: Sorry, but the way your question is stated it seamed you were trying to show that $\rho$  is not an uniform probability on $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the approach for (4). You want to construct $A, B \in D$ so that $\rho_n(A\cup B)$ has two limit points. Let $A$ be the even integers and define $B$ by its characteristic sequence $\chi_B: \mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$ as follows:

Consider the $2^n$-truncations of $\chi_A$:

$$0,
01,
0101,
01010101,
0101010101010101, \dots$$

Define $\chi_B$ by taking the $2^{2n}$-truncation of $\chi_A$, reversing it, and appending to the $2^{2n}$-truncation to the $2^{2n+1}$-truncations of $\chi_B$ and reversing:

$$0,
01,
01{\bf 10},
01100101,
01{\bf 10} 0101{\bf 10101010},\dots$$

Then $\rho(A) = \rho(B) = \frac12$, so $A, B \in D$, and $\chi_{A \cup B}$ is given by

$$0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots$$

Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
\rho_{2^{2n+1}} (A\cup B) &= \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \left(1+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{2k+1} +\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{2k+1}\right)
= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^{2k+1}} \to \frac23
\end{align*}
$$
as $n \to \infty$. On the other hand,
$$
\rho_{2^{2n}}(A\cup B) = \frac12 \rho_{2^{2n-1}}(A\cup B) + \frac12 \to \frac56.
$$
Thus the sequence $(\rho_n)$ has two limits points, so $A \cup B \not \in D$.

Comment: So insightful! :-D